# how to display fragment tabs on login success

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to display my three fragments when users are successfully logged in by using this code but it is not working

```
if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                            editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL, resp.getUser().getEmail());
                            editor.putString(Constants.NAME, resp.getUser().getName());
                            editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, resp.getUser().getUnique_id());
                            editor.apply();
                            goToHome();
```

how do initialize it?

Comment: you may want to post your error stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your fragment `HomeFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`.